# How to assign weights to keywords using python

Tags: python, nlp, text-processing

There are keywords categorized from its HTML tags and need to assign weights to the tags and get the calculated total weight for each keyword separately.

```
H1 tag keywords: ['jquery']
    
H2 tag keywords:['aws', 'jquery']

p tag keywords:['country', 'jquery', 'aws']
```

need to assign weights for tags (example format)

```
H1 - 10
H2 -  5
p  -  3
```

an get the Calculated weights from keyword ( only total is needed)

```
jquery  : 10 + 5 + 3 = 18
aws     : 5 + 3 = 8
country : 3 = 3
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to assign the points to the HTML tags separately but cannot do the required calculation needed.

Comment: how are you storing the values? how are you accessing your data? how can we reproduce your problem?

Comment: I have used Lemmatization and categorized and extracted the keywords from tags the full HTML code - first_headers = ' '.join([e.text for e in soup.find_all('h1')])

Comment: I got the above output from removing common words and Lemmatization- raw1 = first_headers
CORPUS = Common_word_corpus       
corpus = [w.lower() for w in CORPUS] 
processed_H1_tag = [w for w in raw1.split(' ') if w.lower() not in corpus] ......  2) lemmatizer step - output_H1_1 = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(w.lower(), pos=wordnet.VERB) for w in processed_H1_tag]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different ways to solve this, and although this one is not the most elegant one, if we assume you have different lists for h1, h2 and p, you can do as following:

```py
h1list = [e.text for e in soup.find_all('h1')]
h2list = [e.text for e in soup.find_all('h2')]
plist = [e.text for e in soup.find_all('p')]

weightsdict = { 'h1': 10, 'h2': 5, 'p':3 }
stringtoeval = ['jquery', 'aws', 'country']

for s in stringtoeval:
     print(s, weightsdict['h1']*h1list.count(s)+weightsdict['h2']*h2list.count(s)+weightsdict['p']*plist.count(s))
```

Comment: Im getting a error as "expected an indented block" when running this

Comment: How to assign the 'h1' weight to the output variable I get such as -  first_headers = ' '.join([e.text for e in soup.find_all('h1')])

Comment: Is there anyway to identify that 'stringtoeval'  is a p tag output.

Comment: give a try now. you don't know if one of the elements in the string is h1, h2 or p, but if it is none you will get a 0